# Python install previous version of selenium through pip

Tags: python, selenium, pip

How do i install previous version of selenium

```
pip install selenium
```

install the latest version

pip install selenium<3.0.1
gives error
The system cannot find the file specified.

basically i want to install the latest selenium in version 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify version numbers as follows:

```
pip install package==1.0
```